# Scroll to div with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this problem where my nav bar wont scroll to the specified div. I've looked at other examples but I cant seem to resolve the problem.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
</head>

<li><a id="link1" href="#top-page">Intro</a></li>
<li><a id="link2" href="#about">About</a></li>
<li><a id="link3" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

<script>
$("#link1").click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#top-page").offset().top
}, 2000);
});
$("#link2").click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top
}, 2000);
});
 $("#link3").click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#contact").offset().top
 }, 2000);
 });
</script>
```

jsfiddle - 
http://jsfiddle.net/4c0r2gzv/

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have jQuery loaded in your demo. Also, it'll work better if you call `event.preventDefault()`. http://jsfiddle.net/ndcf5kjy/

Comment: It seems to work fine though...

Comment: I linked it in using <script> </script> or am i wrong by using that?

Comment: @MoMartin did you remember to include jquery?

Comment: yeah, it's linked in the head as <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Mo Martin, use the drop-down list in the top-right of JSFiddle to add jQuery. Looks like your code works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script for smoothscroll, which I think is what you want:

```
$(function(){
    $(".scroll").click(function(){
        $("html,body").animate({scrollTop:$("#target").offset().top},"500");return false})
    });
});
```

Replace .scroll with a class of your own or use .scroll. Whatever class you use must be applied to the anchor which is going to be clicked. #target sets the destination. Use your own id or use #target. #target must be applied to the destination. The number is the time taken for the animation to complete in milliseconds; change it to whatever you want.